# Android expand view ontouch of button

Tags: java, android, touch-event

i want to change the view height dynamically like exapnd and collapse and also the position(y) of button should be change ..its like moving the button and according to that exapnding view..
my code is...

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                 int height = (int) event.getY();
                 android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpview =
                 (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                 .getLayoutParams();
                 android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpbutton =
                 (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button
                 .getLayoutParams();
                 lpbutton.topMargin = height;
                 button.setLayoutParams(lpbutton);
                 lpview.height = height;
                 view.setLayoutParams(lpview);

            } 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

but my problem is while expanding it is not smoothly expanding ...any suggestion????

Comment: One suggestion would be to use an animation to expand the view. Refer to APIDemos to get more details on animation and here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html